# Breaking long string without the spaces in Python

Tags: python, string

So, here is a snippet of my code:

```
return "a Parallelogram with side lengths {} and {}, and interior angle 
{}".format(str(self.base), str(self.side), str(self.theta))
```

It goes beyond the 80 chars for good styling in a line, so I did this:

```
return "a Parallelogram with side lengths {} and {}, and interior angle\
{}".format(str(self.base), str(self.side), str(self.theta))
```

I added the "\" to break up the string, but then there is this huge blank gap when I print it.

How would you split the code without distorting it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can put parenthesis around the whole expression:

```
return ("a Parallelogram with side lengths {} and {}, and interior "
        "angle {}".format(self.base, self.side, self.theta))
```

or you could still use `\` to continue the expression, just use separate string literals:

```
return "a Parallelogram with side lengths {} and {}, and interior " \
       "angle {}".format(self.base, self.side, self.theta)
```

Note that there is no need to put `+` between the strings; Python automatically joins consecutive string literals into one:

```
>>> "one string " "and another"
'one string and another'
```

I prefer parenthesis myself.

The `str()` calls are redundant; `.format()` does that for you by default.

Comment: If you've got the parentheses in place, you can also put the line break before or after the `.` character. That's because it is a sort of operator (even though we don't often think of it that way), and operators allow flexible spacing on either side of them.

Comment: @Blckknght: I find any whitespace around `.` in attribute access to be too unreadable and ugly, myself.

Comment: I mostly agree, but when the format string would only have a small bit of itself wrapped on the second line (or when it's indentation causing most of the issue, rather than a long string), it can be useful. I almost always break before the dot, so it's `func("formatstring"<newline_and_indentation_upto_the_(>.format(args))` which seems a bit better than the alternatives.

Comment: And amusingly, at least with my font, my comment indented itself exactly correctly to show what I meant...

Comment: @Blckknght: usually there are better alternatives. Such as defining the longer format string as a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't break the line in between instead use two strings separated by line continuation but best would be to use brackets

```
return ("a Parallelogram with side lengths {} and {}, and interior angle "
"{}".format(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following also works with the newer [string formatting technique](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python), in Python 3+:

```
print(
  f"a Parallelogram with side lengths {self.base} and {self.side}, "
  f"and interior angle {self.theta}"
)
```