# Python when using "def" API - return nothing (or error)

Tags: python, function

I do not know how exactly to ask this question, as I can't share API access. If someone could help with the correct way of asking, will appreciate it.

I have a code which works perfectly fine and executes what I need, BUT when I use this API request code inside the DEF function, it returns with nothing or error...

The error is simple that I cannot get the output, or return with 0 values

This is the code:

```
def sm_main_data():


    #DATA PROCESSING - Impression|Engagements|VideoViews
    urlMain = "https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/" + key.accountId + "/posts/metrics?\
    filter=analytics.timeseries_key.gte(" + config.start + ").lte(" + config.end + ")&\
    filter=channel.eq(" + config.which_social_media + ")&\
    metrics=analytics.engagement_total,analytics.video.views_count,analytics.impressions&\
    dimensions=data_source_id,channel,analytics.timeseries_key.by(" + config.per_what + ")"

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key.token}

    #Receive data from SM (main data) / modified it and save as JSON file
    responseMain = requests.get(urlMain, headers=headers).json()
    pprint.pprint(responseMain)
    pass

sm_main_data()
```

I have tried to print variables inside def:

```
print(key.accountId)
print(config.start)
print(config.end)
print(config.which_social_media)
print(config.per_what)
```

Which all printed correctly.

Currently I'm lost... and cannot get an even theoretical idea about what could go wrong. Why this code does not work inside def function???

**Edit 1.0**

Error

```
{u'errors': [{u'detail': u'`    filter` parameter is not supported.,`    metrics` parameter is not supported.,`    dimensions` parameter is not supported.',
              u'status': u'422',
              u'title': u'Unprocessable Entity'}]}
```

**Edit 1.1**

Code without def

```
#DATA PROCESSING - Impression|Engagements|VideoViews
urlMain = "https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/" + key.accountId + "/posts/metrics?\
filter=analytics.timeseries_key.gte(" + config.start + ").lte(" + config.end + ")&\
filter=channel.eq(" + config.which_social_media + ")&\
metrics=analytics.engagement_total,analytics.video.views_count,analytics.impressions&\
dimensions=data_source_id,channel,analytics.timeseries_key.by(" + config.per_what + ")"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key.token}

#Receive data from SM (main data) / modified it and save as JSON file
responseMain = requests.get(urlMain, headers=headers).json()
pprint.pprint(responseMain)
```

Comment: You'll have to, at the very least, share the error you are getting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Done

Comment: @MartijnPieters but when i remove def, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you see the problem is, that I can't give you access to API, that someone can test it, so I assumed maybe anyone will know why it could happen, that I can test it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what else should I change that you will remove "On Hold" ??

Comment: Ah, your strings are indented, so now the extra whitespace is included in the string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question is, what potentially could be ... that without def sm_main_data(): code working excellent, but when I  use def from this point.... not roper feedback from api?

Comment: The question is, if you remove the `def` line, do you also remove the indentation of all following lines?

Comment: Right. Change `def ...` to `if True:` so you can leave the indentation the same. You'll get the same errors I betcha.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, you are right it does not work with "if True:" How should I change to make it work?.. Sorry i'm a bit lost....

Comment: Not that it matters *in this specific case*, but in future you can link to the [relevant API documentation](https://developers.simplymeasured.com/docs/releases/v1.7.7/03-Analytics%20API#span-data-typegetgetspan-v1analyticsaccount_idpostsmetrics) at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shows you are trying to send parameters with extra spaces before them to the server:

```
`    filter` parameter is not supported.
`    metrics` parameter is not supported.
```

Those extra spaces before the names are part of the parameter name, because you included those in your string:

```
def sm_main_data():
    # ...
    urlMain = "https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/" + key.accountId + "/posts/metrics?\
    filter=analytics.timeseries_key.gte(" + config.start + ").lte(" + config.end + ")&\
    filter=channel.eq(" + config.which_social_media + ")&\
    metrics=analytics.engagement_total,analytics.video.views_count,analytics.impressions&\
    dimensions=data_source_id,channel,analytics.timeseries_key.by(" + config.per_what + ")"

# ^^^ those lines are indented but the whitespace is part of the string
```

You would get the same problem if you had indented the `urlMain` string definition for any other reason, like for a `if` statement or a `try...except` statement, not just a function. You'd have to not indent those parts that are inside a string literal.

Rather than use `\` continuations in the string, you could use [separate string literals to create one long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192268/breaking-long-string-without-the-spaces-in-python/19192282#19192282), or end the string literal with a closing `"` followed by a `+` and a `"` opening quote on the next line:

```
urlMain = (
    "https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/" + 
    key.accountId + "/posts/metrics?" +
    "filter=analytics.timeseries_key.gte(" + config.start + ").lte(" + config.end + ")&" +
    "filter=channel.eq(" + config.which_social_media + ")&" +
    "metrics=analytics.engagement_total,analytics.video.views_count,analytics.impressions&" +
    "dimensions=data_source_id,channel,analytics.timeseries_key.by(" + config.per_what + ")"
)
```

All those `+` concatenations are not very readable, you should really use [string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3) to insert values into a string.

However, you do not need to build a string like that *anyway*, as `requests` can do this *for* you when you give it a dictionary as the `params` argument. Use lists to pass in multiple values for a given parameter name:

```
url = "https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/{k.accountId}/posts/metrics".format(
    k=key)
params = {
    'filter': [  # a list for multiple entries: filter=...&filter=...
        'analytics.timeseries_key.gte({c.start}).lte({c.end})'.format(c=config),
        'channel.eq({c.which_social_media})'.format(c=config),
    ],
    'metrics': (
        'analytics.engagement_total,analytics.video.views_count,'
        'analytics.impressions'),
    'dimensions':
        'data_source_id,channel,'
        'analytics.timeseries_key.by({c.per_what})'.format(c=config),
}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {k.token}'.format(k=key)}
responseMain = requests.get(urlMain, params=params, headers=headers).json()
```

Here I used `str.format()` to insert values from the `config` and `key` objects; note that the placeholders pull out the attributes

Note: I removed the Content-Type header, as that header doesn't apply to a GET request (which doesn't *have* content, the request body is always empty).

Comment: That's works!! But have an extra question, how to modify my code, to make it actually work? is it possible?

Comment: Yes...) Thank you for your help... Sorry for the unclear question but this answer helped me a lot!!!!